# Replace column values dataset with NA based on dates from another column dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, na

I have two datasets:

```
#> dput((h_NDVI))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(15235, 15236, 15237, 15238, 
15239, 15240, 15241, 15242, 15243, 15244, 15245, 15246, 15247, 
15248, 15249, 15250, 15251, 15252, 15253, 15254, 15255, 15256, 
15257, 15258, 15259, 15260, 15261, 15262, 15263, 15264, 15265, 
15266, 15267, 15268, 15269, 15270, 15271, 15272, 15273, 15274, 
15275, 15276, 15277, 15278, 15279, 15280, 15281, 15282, 15283, 
15284, 15285, 15286, 15287, 15288, 15289, 15290, 15291, 15292, 
15293, 15294, 15295, 15296, 15297, 15298, 15299, 15300, 15301, 
15302, 15303, 15304, 15305), class = "Date"), NDVI = c(NA, NA, 
0.294432928636906, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.278673565052068, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.352506101806382, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.377174364841906, 
NA, NA, NA)), row.names = 160:230, class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
#> dput(head(random_h_NDVI,23))
structure(list(N = c(22L, 25L, 27L, 56L, 69L, 81L, 83L, 96L, 
100L, 106L, 124L, 138L, 139L, 150L, 153L, 162L, 171L, 174L, 181L, 
187L, 205L, 206L, 227L), Date = structure(c(15097, 15100, 15102, 
15131, 15144, 15156, 15158, 15171, 15175, 15181, 15199, 15213, 
15214, 15225, 15228, 15237, 15246, 15249, 15256, 15262, 15280, 
15281, 15302), class = "Date"), NDVI = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.2944329, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.3771744)), row.names = c(98L, 91L, 23L, 79L, 163L, 
34L, 191L, 59L, 7L, 213L, 52L, 134L, 209L, 176L, 58L, 165L, 16L, 
92L, 171L, 28L, 164L, 137L, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

A quick explanation of the exercise: I've chosen random points from **h_NDVI** and created the **random_h_NDVI**.

Now I want to replace all values of the *NDVI* column from **h_NDVI** with NA that have a coincident *Date* with **random_h_NDVI** (this includes the NA's which will remain NA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do a join by 'Date' and assign the matching ones to NA

```
> which(!is.na(h_NDVI$NDVI))
[1]  3 16 51 68
library(data.table)
setDT(h_NDVI)[random_h_NDVI, NDVI := NA_real_, on = .(Date)]
> which(!is.na(h_NDVI$NDVI))
[1] 16 51
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
h_NDVI$NDVI[h_NDVI$Date %in% random_h_NDVI$Date] <- NA_real_
```

Comment: thank you @akrun. I would rather prefer a matching through the Date column and directly deleting all values from NDVI column with the same date of **random_h_NDVI** because I have several large datasets and through the analysis process is easier to track the dates which have numeric values than by index row position.

Comment: assign the NDVI to NA